# Change Iframe YouTube Video On Entering Code In Text Input

Tags: javascript, iframe, src

I want someone to be able to enter the YouTube code in a text input box and on blur or on change it change the YouTube video in the iFrame instantly.

Here is what I have that is not working...

```
<input type="text" name="videourl" value="$videourl" style="width:400px;" onchange="newVideo()" />

<iframe id="myIframe" width="230" height="129" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/$videourl?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
function newVideo() {
    var select = document.getElementById('videourl');
    document.getElementById('myIframe').src.select;
}
</script>
```

I believe something in my JavaScript is wrong, I just can't figure it out. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `id` attribute to your input tag:

```
id="videourl"
```

Transfer the user input to the appropriate place in the src string...

```
var select=document.getElementById('videourl').value;
document.getElementById('myIframe').src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+select+'?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0';
```

Comment: @RandyThomas Are you just trying to put some leading & trailing strings on the user input and set the myIframe src?

Comment: that worked perfectly. I knew I was close but just not there lol. The `onchange()` is working as well. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Where's id `videourl` ?

Comment: @PedroLobito  Yep.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure of what you're trying to do, but with jQuery you can use something like:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#yt_id').on('input', function() {
          $("#myIframe").attr("src","https://www.youtube.com/embed/"+$('#yt_id').val()+"?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0");
       });
     });
</script>

<input maxlength="11" type="text" id="yt_id" name="videourl" value="_g-dyXWUov8" style="width:400px;" />
<iframe id="myIframe" width="230" height="129" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Q1rhoq77dcY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

[jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tuga/gbvbnpck/11/)